# Adding a revenue calculation code to an existing code

Tags: javascript, html

I have code where a sub unit's revenue gets calculated after selecting assumptions. I want to add another independent sub unit where its revenue also gets calculated after selecting one of two totally different assumptions. I have placed the original code below for which the sub unit and assumption has to be added. Greatly appreciate your help. I asked Chatgpt and used their codes but their codes dont properly pick up the new set of assumptions and the revenue does not calculated for the second revenue sub unit

```js
// JavaScript to handle user input and update revenue table
document.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.id.startsWith('assumption') || e.target.id.startsWith('selectAssumption')) {
    updateRevenueTable();
  }
});

function updateRevenueTable() {
  // Get user input values for assumptions
  const assumption01_3Q24E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption01_3Q24E').value);
  const assumption02_3Q24E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption02_3Q24E').value)
  const assumption01_4Q24E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption01_4Q24E').value);
  const assumption02_4Q24E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption02_4Q24E').value)
  const assumption01_1Q25E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption01_1Q25E').value);
  const assumption02_1Q25E = parseFloat(document.getElementById('assumption02_1Q25E').value)

  // Get 2Q24 revenue numbers
  const revenue2Q24 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('revenue2Q24').textContent.replace(/,/g, ''));

  // Determine which assumptions to use based on checkbox states
  const useAssumption01 = document.getElementById('selectAssumption01').checked;
  const useAssumption02 = document.getElementById('selectAssumption02').checked;

  // Perform your calculations based on assumptions for 3Q24E
  let selectedAssumption = useAssumption01 ? assumption01_3Q24E : 0;
  selectedAssumption += useAssumption02 ? assumption02_3Q24E : 0;
  const revenue3Q24E = calculateRevenue(selectedAssumption, 0, revenue2Q24);

  // Update table cells with calculated values
  document.getElementById('revenue3Q24E').textContent = numberWithCommas(revenue3Q24E.toFixed(2));

  // Calculate assumptions for 4Q24E and 1Q25E based on revenue from 3Q24E
  const revenue3Q24EValue = parseFloat(document.getElementById('revenue3Q24E').textContent.replace(/,/g, ''));
  selectedAssumption = useAssumption01 ? assumption01_4Q24E : 0;
  selectedAssumption += useAssumption02 ? assumption02_4Q24E : 0;
  const revenue4Q24E = calculateRevenue(selectedAssumption, 0, revenue3Q24EValue);
  selectedAssumption = useAssumption01 ? assumption01_1Q25E : 0;
  selectedAssumption += useAssumption02 ? assumption02_1Q25E : 0;
  const revenue1Q25E = calculateRevenue(selectedAssumption, 0, revenue4Q24E);

  // Update table cells with calculated values
  document.getElementById('revenue4Q24E').textContent = numberWithCommas(revenue4Q24E.toFixed(2));
  document.getElementById('revenue1Q25E').textContent = numberWithCommas(revenue1Q25E.toFixed(2));
}

// Replace this function with your actual revenue calculation logic
function calculateRevenue(assumption, _, baseRevenue) {
  // Replace this with your actual revenue calculation logic
  // Example: Assume a simple calculation for illustration
  return baseRevenue * (1 + assumption / 100);
}

// Function to add commas to numbers for better formatting
function numberWithCommas(x) {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}


updateRevenueTable();
```

```html
<table id="revenueTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Period</th>
      <th></th>

      <th>4Q23</th>
      <th>1Q24</th>
      <th>2Q24</th>
      <th>3Q24E</th>
      <th>4Q24E</th>
      <th>1Q25E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Revenue from contract customer</td>
      <td></td>

      <td id="revenue4Q23">52,957,361,432</td>
      <td id="revenue1Q24">53,412,305,980</td>
      <td id="revenue2Q24">59,245,081,755</td>
      <td id="revenue3Q24E"></td>
      <td id="revenue4Q24E"></td>
      <td id="revenue1Q25E"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Assumption 01 - YoY%</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectAssumption01" onchange="updateRevenueTable()"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>

      <td><input type="number" id="assumption01_3Q24E" value="-698"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="assumption01_4Q24E" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="assumption01_1Q25E" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Assumption 02 - Global GDP</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="selectAssumption02" onchange="updateRevenueTable()"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="assumption02_3Q24E" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="assumption02_4Q24E" value="0"></td>
      <td><input type="number" id="assumption02_1Q25E" value="0"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```